# React event handlers not binding properly

Tags: meteor, reactjs, event-handling, anonymous-function, semantic-ui

I am building a React app with Semantic UI in Meteor. I have had two places where event handlers don't seem to be functioning in any capacity, and I haven't found anything online with a problem to the same extent.

Below is my React class. I have tried various ways of calling the eventHandler methods, but nothing works. That also seems irrelevant since I can't even get an anonymous function to run.

```
SaveSearchPopout = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {username: "", queryname: ""};
},
handleUsernameChange:function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({username: e.target.value})
},
handleQuerynameChange:function(e) {
    this.setState({queryname: e.target.value})
},
handleSave:function(e) {
    console.log("handling save");console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("saving!");
    return false;
},

render: function() {
    console.log(this);
    return (
        <div className="ui modal saveSearchPopout">
            <div className="header">Save Search</div>
            <div className="content">
                <form className="ui form" onSubmit={function() {console.log("test");}}>
                    <div className="field">
                        <input type="text" name="username"
                            placeholder="Username" 
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onChange={function() {console.log("update")}} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <input type="text" name="queryname"
                            placeholder="Name this search"
                            value={this.state.queryname}
                            onChange={this.handleQuerynameChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="actions">
                        <div className="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit">Click</button>
                        <button className="ui button" type="button"
                            onClick={function() {console.log("saving");}}>Save</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

The class is rendered from another classes method which looks like:

```
saveSearch: function() {        
    var backingDiv = document.createElement('div');
    backingDiv.id = 'shadowPopupBack';
    document.getElementsByClassName('content-container')[0].appendChild(backingDiv);
    ReactDOM.render(<SaveSearchPopout />, backingDiv);
    //this.props.saveSearch;
    $('.ui.modal.saveSearchPopout')
        .modal({
            closeable:false,
            onDeny: function() {
                var container = document.getElementsByClassName('content-container')[0];
                var modalContainer = document.getElementById('shadowPopupBack');
                container.removeChild(modalContainer);
            }
        })
        .modal('show');
},
```

The only button that works is the Semantic UI cancel button.

Has anyone else run into this or have any idea what I am missing.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer here. [Semantic UI modal component onClose with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172613/semantic-ui-modal-component-onclose-with-react)
and I haven't worked through it yet, but it looks like this is more Reactive solution than using jQuery to bind eventHandlers: http://www.agilityfeat.com/blog/2015/09/using-react-js-and-semantic-ui-to-create-stylish-apps.
Hope this is helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the case, but in newer versions of React (or JSX), when you pass a function to an HTML component or a custom component, that function is not automatically bound to `this` instance.

You must bind them manually. For example:

```
onChange={this.handleQuerynameChange.bind(this)}
```

Or you could use arrow functions, because they will automatically bind to this:

```
onChange={e => this.handleQuerynameChange(e)}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this and it's variations with no change. It also doesn't help explain why an anonymous function won't run.